# Sending e-mail from gmail SMTP with ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, smtp, gmail

I'm creating app and it return error. This is part of configuration SMTP connection in web.config file:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" 
                 port="587" 
                 userName="mymail@gmail.com" 
                 password="mypassword" 
                 enableSsl="true"
                 defaultCredentials="false"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

And below is code in Helpers controller:

```
namespace Subscription.Helpers
{
    public static class MailHelper
    {
        private static SmtpClient _smtpClient;

        static MailHelper()
        {
            _smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        }

        public static void SendEmail(List<string> recipientAddress, string subject, string news)
        {
            using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
            {
                mail.From = new MailAddress("mymail@gmail.com", "Google.com", Encoding.UTF8);

                foreach(string address in recipientAddress)
                {
                    mail.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(address));
                }

                mail.Subject = subject;
                mail.Body = news;
                mail.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;

                _smtpClient.Send(mail);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I want to send email to all addresses from database it return unhandled exception with communicate: "The SMTP host was not specified" and line "_smtpClient.Send(mail);" in source error. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Surely the `SmtpClient` needs the host details assigning to it directly: `_smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"` and `_smtpClient.Port = 587`. Someone please correct me if I'm mistaken, but I've not seen `SmtpClient` read its settings from `web.config` before.

Comment: No, that's what the web.config section is for. SmtpClient should read it from there. The issue is the missing attributes on the `<smtp>` tag and/or the OP added to some other Web.config than the one at the root of the site.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I didn't realise it did that.

Answer (score 0):

First add descriptions to your  tag like this:

```
<smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="username@gmail.com">
```

Then in your code behind add smtp.EnableSsl = true; and remove it from you web.config.